# How get specific file from directory using apache camel in java?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have an scenario, a directory contains various file named pattern filehhmm like:

hh=hours
mm=minutes

dir:
file1200.txt
file1210.txt
file1220.txt
otherfile1.txt
otherfile2.txt

I need to find latest file based on hh:mm, in my case it would be file1220.txt

Comment: What have you tried (can you show us your code?) and where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Sort your files (descending) using a custom comparator (based on the timestamp part), and limit the polling to one single file.
Take care to apply the sorting **BEFORE** limiting the number of polled files (see `eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll`)

```
<route>
  <from uri="file:mydir?maxMessagesPerPoll=1&eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false"/>
  <sort comparator="#class:com.mycompany.MyCusomComparator">
```